# Bash script run by PHP exec() not doing redirection properly

Tags: php, bash, exec, io-redirection

I have a script that takes some parameters and redirects the output of a heredoc to another file, in order to create a virtual host file for the web server.
When I run the script in the command line, it executes fine and the file is created, but when I run it using PHP's exec or shell_exec it doesn't create the file. Everything else (echoing or trying to simply return the output instead of redirecting it) runs fine - just creating the file doesn't happen and I receive no indication that there was a problem.

Here is my code: 
create_vhost.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Use the template to create the vhost file
echo "Creating vhost file in sites-available"
sudo /absolute/path/to/vhost_template.sh $1 $2 > /etc/nginx/sites-available/$2
service nginx restart
```

I run the above script like so: `/absolute/path/to/create_vhost.sh site_id domain.com` and it works perfectly using ssh with Terminal.

For reference, the vhost_template file is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

SITE_ID=$1
DOMAIN=$2

#define the template.
cat  << EOF
[template code here with $SITE_ID and $DOMAIN parameters somewhere]
EOF
```

However, if I run it in PHP like so:

```
return shell_exec("/absolute/path/to/create_vhost.sh site_id domain.com");
```

I get the output just fine, but no file is created! And like I said, if I drop the redirection, then even in PHP I see the output of the template file with no problem.

I've been looking at this for hours but I'm just stumped. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Just thought I'd mention that I thought it's probably a permissions thing, but I tried using sudo within shell_exec(), and using visudo to give the www-data user sudo privileges. Still the same problem...

Comment: maybe the webserver user doesn't have write access to the directory your trying to create a file in

Comment: @DevZer0 probably not, but if I use sudo to run my script, wouldn't that not matter any more? Or am I just stupid. I've previously used another script (this one was ruby, not bash) that was run by the webserver user and wrote to the same directory...
As I mentioned in the post, I tried running with sudo, and still no luck.

Comment: run this and see what you get `return shell_exec("/absolute/path/to/create_vhost.sh site_id domain.com 2>&1");`

Comment: Ok, that's more like it. Running without sudo I get permission denied for pretty much every line of the script. With sudo the PHP script returns no data at all... So it seems I've messed up somewhere with allowing the www-data user to have root privileges on that file. Thanks, I'll look into it a bit more... At least for now I know what was going wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Just got it all working. I'm pretty sure my code in the is the same as it was before, so I'm not even sure what I did to fix it, but I commented out every line before running the script, then uncommented each line one at a time, and for some reason it works now. Very strange. Thanks a lot for the help with debugging it though - can I 'vote' for a comment at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be missing out some vital information that is sent to `stderr` so you can try redirecting the `stderr` output to `stdout`. Will help you debug the issue.

```
return shell_exec("/absolute/path/to/create_vhost.sh site_id domain.com 2>&1");
```

Comment: Many thanks! (again). This helped me debug the situation and in the end I got everything working ;)